# Subset R data frame based on string matches in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with three columns and thousands of rows. The first two columns (x and y) contain character strings, and the third (z) contains numeric data. I need to subset the data frame based on matching values in both of the first two columns.

```
    x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k")
    y <- c("h", "b", "k", "a", "g", "d", "i", "c", "f", "j")
    z <- c(1:10)
    df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

       x y  z
    1  a h  1
    2  b b  2
    3  c k  3
    4  d a  4
    5  f g  5
    6  g d  6
    7  h i  7
    8  i c  8
    9  j f  9
    10 k j 10
```

Say this is my table, and the values I am interested in are "a", "c", "f", "h" and "k". I only want to return the rows in which both x and y contain one of the five, so in this case rows 1 and 3.

I've tried:

```
    df2 <- filter(df, 
             x == ("a" | "c" | "f" | "h" | "k") & 
             y == ("a" | "c" | "f" | "h" | "k"))
```

but this doesn't work for factors or character strings. Is there an equivalent or another way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this returns what you are looking for:

```
# build vector of necessary elements
mustHaves <- c("a", "c", "f", "h", "k")
# perform subsetting
df[with(df, x %in% mustHaves & y %in% mustHaves),]
  x y z
1 a h 1
3 c k 3
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x, y, z, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: A perfect answer, and so quick! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`

```
df2 <- filter(df, 
                x %in% c("a" ,"c","f" ,"h","k") & 
                  y %in% c("a" ,"c","f" ,"h","k"))
df2
  x y z
1 a h 1
2 c k 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works perfectly. So my mistake was using == instead of %in%. I am quite new to R, so I hadn't come across %in% before.

Comment: No problem, yep, ``%in%`` basically matches any string within the following vector. Consider accepting one of the above solutions so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
df2 <- filter(df, grepl("[acfhk]",x) & grepl("[acfhk]",y))
```

using `dplyr` package

Comment: Thank you, this also works perfectly. Three different ways to achieve the same thing. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: You are welcome. It is probably worth checking which is the fastest if you expect to process really big datasets.